# QFontDialog keeps adding "Monospace" when I use setCurrentFont

Tags: qt, fonts

I solved my first problem. Every time I create a QFontComboBox, I get "Monospace" listed but selecting it gives me another font. Fine - I have removed all fonts that are not in the QFontDatabase. That removes the "Monospace" entry.

But when I use setCurrentFont with a courier font, it will add that option back in to the pull down.

This is on Linux with QT 5.15 (I just tried 6.6.1 and that does the same).

I have attempted to do my own font matching so that I am setting a font that it certainly should know about but that has not helped. Here is my latest test code -

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    QFontDatabase db;
    QStringList fontFamilies = db.families();
    QStringList filteredFonts;

    QFont defaultFont("Courier");
    bool foundDefault = false;
    for (const QString& family : fontFamilies)
    {
        if (family.startsWith("Courier"))
        {
            defaultFont = QFont(family);
            foundDefault = true;
        }
        if (QFont(family).exactMatch())
        {
            filteredFonts.append(family);
        }
    }

    fontComboBox->clear();
    fontComboBox->addItems(filteredFonts);

    if (foundDefault)
    {
        fontComboBox->setCurrentFont(defaultFont);
    }
    connect(fontComboBox, &QFontComboBox::currentFontChanged, this, &MainWindow::fontUpdate);

}

void MainWindow::fontUpdate(const QFont& font)
{

}
```

On my system, it's finding "Courier 10 Pitch" and using that as the default. Is there anything I can do to stop that bogus entry popping up?

The user problem is that they pick "Monospace" but end up getting "DejaVu Sans Mono" when they go back in again.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: What if you use [`setFontFilters()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontcombobox.html#fontFilters-prop) with all flags *except* `MonospacedFonts`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried that and sure enough, I can't select Monospace but I also can't select a whole load of other fonts such as "Courier 10 Pitch". The problem I have is, if you set "Courier 10 Pitch" (for example) as the selected font, it adds "Monospace" which the user can then pick but it doesn't really exist as a font so you can't set it as an option in the ComboBox - they get the nearest hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `setCurrentFont()` is called, QFontComboBox *always* updates its internal list of family names.

The solution is to never call that function directly and use the basic `setCurrentIndex()` of QComboBox, which is internally connected to a function that checks the current font and eventually updates it.

Unfortunately I cannot write in C++, but the following Python example based on your original code should be clear enough.

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fontComboBox = QFontComboBox()
        self.preview = QLabel('Hello world!')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.fontComboBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.preview)
        

        fontFamilies = QFontDatabase().families()
        filteredFonts = []

        defaultFont = QFont('Courier')
        if QFontInfo(defaultFont).family() == defaultFont.family():
            defaultFamily = defaultFont.family()
        else:
            defaultFamily = ''

        for family in fontFamilies:
            font = QFont(family)
            if QFontInfo(font).family() == family:

                if family.startswith('Courier') and not defaultFamily:
                    defaultFamily = family

                filteredFonts.append(family)

        self.fontComboBox.model().setStringList(filteredFonts)

        self.fontComboBox.currentFontChanged.connect(self.preview.setFont)

        if defaultFamily:
            defaultIndex = self.fontComboBox.findText(defaultFamily)
            if defaultIndex >= 0:
                self.fontComboBox.setCurrentIndex(defaultIndex)
```

The last block also shows a possible alternative to `setCurrentFont()`, in case you need a similar function, which could be implemented with something like this:

```py
    def setCurrentFont(self, font):
        fi = QFontInfo(font)
        index = self.fontComboBox.findText(fi.family())

        if index < 0 and ' [' in fi.family():
            # strip *foundry* names
            family = fi.family()[:fi.family().index(' [')]
            index = self.fontComboBox.findText(family, Qt.MatchStartsWith)

        if index >= 0:
            self.fontComboBox.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

Comment: Only just noticed your reply. I will try this out when I get some spare time in the next few days. Thanks for looking into it. Looks promising!

Comment: This solution worked though it turned out that I didn't need most of the setCurrentFont example that you kindly provided. Here's my version in C++ with the code I didn't need commented out. For me, the fi.family() was just returning "Courier 10 point" so no need to look for square brackets.
Ah - pasting the code results in a "too long" message so I'll edit the original. Thanks again.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include answers. For future reference, wait for responses from answerers and eventually consider posting an answer on your own. In this case it won't be necessary, the fact that you realized you didn't need `setCurrentFont()` anymore is now somehow irrelevant, as the current answer already covers that aspect and further more. The font info part is also quite important for completeness and compliancy with the expected behavior of Qt, so while it *may* not be necessary for you (and just as far as you believe) it **must** be used, as that's how the widget works.

Comment: Just noticed this - thanks for the reply. I will use the check on foundry names then in case it's an issue on another platform/environment. Do you think there's any value in posting the C++ version?